# Building matplotlib from git in Ubuntu 14.04.2 for Python3.4.x

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, matplotlib

I am trying to install Matplotlib latest from source using the following steps:

1) git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
2) cd ~/matplotlib; sudo python3 setup.py install

However, I get the following error, which I don't fully understand:

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.dev1]
                python: yes [3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)  [GCC
                        4.8.2]]
              platform: yes [linux]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.10.0.dev0+fba3140]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.5.2]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.0]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2012c]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.1.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.1]
                libagg: yes [Requires patches that have not been merged
                        upstream. Using local copy.]


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 153, in <module>
        result = package.check()
      File "/home/srini/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 900, in check
        min_version='2.3', version=version)
      File "/home/srini/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 446, in _check_for_pkg_config
        if (not is_min_version(version, min_version)):
      File "/home/srini/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 173, in is_min_version
        return found_version >= expected_version
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/version.py", line 76, in __ge__
        c = self._cmp(other)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/version.py", line 343, in _cmp
        if self.version < other.version:
        TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Could somebody take a look and tell me if I am missing any dependencies?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly suggest against installing via sudo, it it much better to use virtual environments.  You are missing freetype-dev .  Getting this to fail gracefully is one of the worst warts in the build system.

Comment: As I said, I did use sudo python3 setup.py install command.  Are you suggesting that I use sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib.  This will install Matplotlib from Ubuntu software center, which is not up to date.  Moreover, I couldn't find freetype-dev package.  How do I find it and from where?

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the problem.  I needed to install libfreetype-dev package through the following command first: **sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev**, and then repeating the steps 1 and 2 that I said before.  Thanks for your help.